# Bash Scripting - unexpected token fi

Tags: bash, shell

So I am trying to write a bash script that states:

*if file a exists, and directory b exists, run composer install, check for the vendor folder. if we found it - echo something out and exit.*

But it keeps saying:

```
./composerrun.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./composerrun.sh: line 6: `    fi'
```

And I am too new to bash to understand how this closing "brace" is wrong:

```
#!/bin/bash
if checkForComposerJson && checkForAisisCore
    composer install
    if checkForVendor
        echo "Found vendor"; exit;
    fi
fi

function checkForAisisCore {
    if [-d "AisisCore/"]
    then 
        return 0;
    else
       echo "would you like us to create the directory?" yn,
       case $yn in
           Yes ) 
               mkdir "AisisCore/";
               if [-d "AisisCore/"]
                   return 0;;
               else
                   echo "We could not create the directory as you requested";
                   return 1;;
               end
           No ) return 1;;
           * ) echo "Please put in either yes or no";
       esac
   fi
}

function checkForVendor(){
  if [-d "vender/adam.balan/aisis-core/"]
      return 0;
  else
      "Something is wrong. We could not find the vendor/ folder. Please check that you are running this script inside of your theme or project folder.";
      return 1;
  fi
}

function checkForComposerJson(){
    if [-f "composer.json"]
        return 0;
    else
        echo "You need composer.json with appropriate information about AisisCore";
        return 1;
    fi
}
```

Also, my mkdir, where I make the directory if it doesn't exist - the check I do after words - is it worth it?

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ will find these issues automatically without needing to get humans involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot a `then`. It should be:

```
if checkForComposerJson && checkForAisisCore
then  ## <-------------------
    composer install
    if checkForVendor
    then  ## <-------------------

        echo "Found vendor"; exit;
    fi
fi
```

Comment: @LogicLooking The same is true for the rest of the `if`'s You are missing a couple of more of them :)