# What is going on in this script - Bash Scripting

Tags: bash, shell

So i [recently asked about the unexpected token fi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924137/bash-scripting-unexpected-token-fi/18924156?noredirect=1#comment27940668_18924156) and fixed those errors. Now I am getting different errors. can some one please read through my script and point out or fix all the errors you see -I am new to bash and not getting half of these errors. For example:

```
$ composerrun.sh
./composerrun.sh: line 2: checkForComposerJson: command not found
./composerrun.sh: line 27: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./composerrun.sh: line 27: `           [Nn]*) '
```

When I run:

```
#!/bin/bash


# We need to see if the AisisCore/ Directory exists.
# If it doesn't we will try and create it for you.
# Then to be safe - we check if it exists.
function checkForAisisCore {
    if [[-d "AisisCore/"]]
    then 
        return 0;
    else
       read -p "Would you like us to create the directory?" yn,
       case $yn in
           [[Yy]]*) 
               mkdir "AisisCore/";
               if [[-d "AisisCore/"]]
               then
                   return 0;
               else
                   echo "We could not create the directory as you requested";
                   return 1;
               end
               ;;
           [[Nn]]*) 
               return 1;
               ;;
           *) 
               echo "Please put in either yes or no";
       esac
   fi
}

# We check for the aisis-core inside of vender inside of adam.balan.
# If it exists return true.
# If Not, then alert the user and return false.
function checkForVendor(){
  if [[-d "vender/adam.balan/aisis-core/"]]
  then
      return 0;
  else
      echo "Something is wrong. We could not find the vendor/ folder. Please check that you are running this script inside of your theme or project folder.";
      return 1;
  fi
}

# We need to know if composer.json exists.
# If it does we return true.
# If not - we alert the user.
function checkForComposerJson(){
    if [[-f "composer.json"]]
    then
        return 0;
    else
        echo "You need composer.json with appropriate information about AisisCore";
        return 1;
    fi
}

# ================================ [ Core ] ================================

# Core program.
#
# Check if the composer.json and AisisCore/ exist.
# Run composer install.
# Check for vendor folder.
# If all is good - echo Found Vendor and exit. (For now).
if checkForComposerJson && checkForAisisCore
then
    composer install
    if checkForVendor
    then
        echo "Found vendor"; exit;
    fi
fi
```

I'm sure there's hundreds of errors and issues but I cant see them because I don't know bash. I think I am on the right track though. How ever I could use a second set of eyes on this script to be like "what are you doing ... "

---

---

Comment: Read the [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) page and clean up your whitespace – some of the above is syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your functions before using them.  Separate case clauses with double semicolons (`;;`).  Prefer `[[` and `]]` to `[` and `]` (see [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542832/bash-if-difference-between-square-brackets-and-double-square-brackets)), as they can lead to fewer surprises.

Comment: Ok I updated the code example to better reflect this but it still get the same error, minus the `./composerrun.sh: line 2: checkForComposerJson: command not found`

Comment: The error on line 27 is because after the Yy conditional, bash expects you to add a line with just `;;` before you start the Nn conditional.  Same goes for just before the wildcard case.

Comment: Ok so I managed to add in the `;;` where I believe they should go, like you said but now bash hates them ... its like `unexpected token ';;'`

Comment: @LogicLooking You've overreplaced the square brackets. In the case statement, `[Yy]` represents a pattern that matches either `Y` or `y`. In an if statement, `[[ ... ]]` is a `bash` conditional expression, which is a more robust alternative to the `test`/`[` command.

Comment: @chepner Oh - so the `[[]]` should be repelaced with `[]` ?? for the Yy and Nn, if thats the case it still doesnt like the `;;`